# Blank lines in zsh loop

Tags: zsh

Running a loop in zsh like the one below gives blank lines in the output (ignore the triviality of this loop; it's just an example. A more realistic example might be running `mysql -s -e "show databases;"` and doing something for each database).

```
for foo in $(cat test.txt); do
    echo $foo
done



alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
```

In this example, if `test.txt` has four lines, three blank lines appear. If it had five lines, four blank lines would appear. In my MySql example, there would be one fewer blank lines than there are MySql databases.

What is causing these blank lines, and how can I prevent them? Running the same script in Bash doesn't give the blank lines.

---

**Edit**: It appears the Oh My Zsh is the culprit, though I haven't yet figured out why. If I comment out `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` in `.zshrc`, the blank lines no longer appear.

Comment: have you tried looking at output of your script with `set -x` or `#!/bin/zsh -x` in the beginning of it?

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the suggestion. Running `set -x` is outputting a TON of stuff, most of it coming from Oh My Zsh. I haven't solved the issue yet, but it is leading me in the right direction.

Comment: you can set `set -x` before the code you want to view debug output for, and disable it with `set +x` afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yes, ~/.oh-my-zsh is the culprit.  Going into ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh

```
#Appears at the beginning of (and during) of command execution
function omz_termsupport_preexec {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extended_glob
  local CMD=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|rake|-*)]} #cmd name only, or if this is sudo or ssh, the next cmd
  local LINE="${2:gs/$/\\$}"
  LINE="${LINE:gs/%/%%}"
  title "$CMD" "%100>...>$LINE%<<"
}
```

We see that it attempts to set the title to the whole command including the things that come after the command, lopping off prefixes like sudo and doing some escaping of characters like $ and %. But for some reason, when you do a cat, it throws in some newlines.  For a quick fix, I'm hobbling oh-my-zsh a bit by just setting the title to $CMD, like so:

```
#Appears at the beginning of (and during) of command execution
function omz_termsupport_preexec {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extended_glob
  local CMD=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|rake|-*)]} #cmd name only, or if this is sudo or ssh, the next cmd
  ## Removing command argument parsing because of cat bug
  #local LINE="${2:gs/$/\\$}"
  #LINE="${LINE:gs/%/%%}"
  #title "$CMD" "%100>...>$LINE%<<"
  title "$CMD" 
}
```

I've gone back through the recent-ish history of this file on oh-my-zsh's github, but it appears this bug has been there for some time.  The "right" answer is probably to do some nested expansion around $LINE that removes blank and newlines and make a pull request to oh-my-zsh. But my zsh foo is still too weak for this.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that Bash is somehow filtering out the whitespace completely. An easy fix for this is to grep a little.

Example:

```
for foo in $(grep -v '^$' test.txt); do
    # The quotes are recommended to make sure you shell won't do weird things with the variables
    echo "$foo"
done
```

Comment: That didn't work. I get no output at all, as `grep -v '' test.txt` outputs nothing. Note that `test.txt` does not contain any blank lines, but it does have newlines at the end of each line. If I change the contents to separated by spaces, rather than newlines, I don't get the blank lines. But `cat`ing a file was just an example; the output of the actual command (such as `mysql) will have newlines in it.

Comment: The `grep -v ''` should filter out all blank lines, but it won't filter out all whitespace. Can you give the output of the first lines of `cat test.txt | hexdump` (or whatever `cat text.txt` is in your case)?

Comment: @WoLpH Have you actually tried `grep -v '' test.txt` on a file? Does it actually do what you say it does?

Comment: @MarkkuK.: I did, but I just noticed now that it doesn't work with the stock version (I have wrapped a lot of my shell commands for convenience, in the case of `''` I automatically insert `'^$'`. I've updated the answer with a version that should work everywhere.